# Base64 encoded data maximum size

Tags: .net, security, encoding, base64

I have a security mechanism that implements symmetric algorithm **RijndaelManaged**. I managed to find information what is the maximum size of encrypted data using **RijndaelManaged** for particular IV. According to my calculations it will be 128 bytes. However I need to convert these 128 bytes to string using Base64. Is there a way to calculate maximum number of chars that Base64 encoding will use to encode input byte array of size 128?

Thanks,Pawel

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Absolutely - [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) takes 4 characters to represent every 3 bytes. (Padding is applied for binary data which isn't an exact multiple of 3 bytes.) So 128 bytes will always be  172 characters. (The way to work this out is that base64 represents 6 bits in each character (2<sup>6</sup> = 64); therefore 3 bytes = 24 bits = 4 base-64 characters.)

Answer (score 6):

A base 64 encoded string will use 4 characters for every 3 bytes (or part thereof). So 128 bytes would be 172 base 64 characters.

Comment: I am getting a resulted string of 172 chars length, but when i display string.getBytes().length then the length is also 172. I want 128 bytes only.

Comment: @UsmanRana: This might be best answered by asking a new question. Though chances are you are just not actually using the Base64 encode/decode fucntions properly. I'm not sure what `string.getBytes()` is in this case since string has no such method. If you are using Encoding.GetBytes then I'd expect that to be the same. You are presumably not using `Convert.FromBase64String` because the output would not be the same length. Basically you need much more information for this to be answerable and comments are not the place to give this.

Comment: Though once you have asked the question feel free to link here and I'll take a look.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Please refer to the following link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38632955/how-to-get-128-bytes-of-base64-encoded-string-of-172-characters-in-android

Comment: @UsmanRana Hi man, I was browsing this post and saw that you said it gave back 172 chars and you want 128 bytes only. Lenght of chars has nothing to do with the bytes in this case. This is due the fact that every 4 characters represent 3 bytes.  Chars length is not the same as the amount of bytes used. 

The length you counter was 172 
The amount of bytes per 4 = 3
"Math" 172 / 4 * 3 is the same as  172 * 0.75 which is 129 which is 128 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

In **Java**:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[128];
int base64Length = bytes.length / 3 * 4; // Strictly integer division
if (bytes.length % 3 != 0)
{
    base64Length += 4; // Extra padding characters will be added
}
System.out.println(bytes.length + " bytes will be encoded in " + base64Length + " characters.");
```

So, where the input `bytes.length == 128`, the output will be `base64Length == 172` characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check this programatically, you can do so by checking the modulus. Here's some psudocode (no particular language) :

```
function base64Inflation (numBytes)
    minimumBase64Bytes = roundDown(numBytes / 3 * 4)    
    modulus = numberOfBytes % 3             // Assuming % is the modulo operator
    if modulus == 0 
        return minimumBase64Bytes           // Exact fit! No padding required.
    else
        return minimumBase64Bytes + 4       // Doesn't quite fit. We need to pad.
```

I've also implemented the same logic in golang:

http://play.golang.org/p/JK9XPAle5_